# AR.js library in Angular, perfomance problem

Tags: angular, performance, augmented-reality, frame-rate, ar.js

**What's the problem?**

I used the AR.js library to create an augmented website solution. My goal is to create a progressive web app to use on every devices like phone, tablet or laptop.

My solution is an Angular project and I included aframe’s library and ar.js library thanks to solutions that I have seen on different websites (AR.js documentation, Github, Medium and others).

I used barcode solution with 3x3 markers. It works well, I detect markers and I can detect some events (like click, marker found, marker lost) thanks to your solution.

I created my ar content in an angular component with an in the html component and some others components (like text or gltf-model) in the typescript component.
I made my solution in https protocol to use it on Chrome or on others navigators.

I have also a problem with fps (frame per second). In fact, my solution has 50 fps on my laptop (but it's not already really fluent). But on my tablet, it only gets 15 fps.

I tried to create a new blank project as the same method that I did to know if there is a problem with my models imported or if there is a problem with my solution.

I obtain same results (with the blank project): 50 fps on a laptop but only 15 fps on tablet. Maybe it’s a problem with my tablet ? What do you think about my issue?

Anyone has ever tried to use the ar.js library? With good performance?

If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to ask.

Thanks a lot for your help!

**Operating System and Device Name**

Tablet : Samsung Galaxy Tab A6

Mobile : Huawei P20Lite

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, implement ARjs in an Angular written environment? If so, it's bound to be a bit all over the place. Typescript is not the best platform for this uses case. If I were you I'd just add AR.js on a different page and redirect to this page. This way it would work on a fullscreen and would have any compatibility issues for different operating systems.

Comment: Yes that what I did. I implement AR.js in an Angular project. In the first version of my project, I made a static html page which I displayed with an iframe. It's a bit what you mean? But I would like to show some Angular components in my augmented reality page for IoT aspects. That why I implement AR.js in Angular. It's work but the performance are very bad and so it's not enjoyfull and usefull for users. I don't know how to use ar.js and display some IoT informations with good performance.

Comment: You'll have a hard time trying to get a smooth experience when you add Angular components to ARjs, it's not really built for it. You can however convert the Angular additions to JS and add ot directly to your ARjs in your iframe.